# How do you link web addresses in comments?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I have seen comments that "neatly" link web addresses instead of having the "ugly" html specification in the comment. Is the only way to do this with the same markup that is used for links in questions and answers, or is there some other markup technique to do it?

In following markup the word "use" would be a link.

```
Question [use][1]

  [1]: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions
```

Comment: The point is that for questions and answers you of course have editor controls to do links automagically. In comments you have to manually code them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use this: square brackets for link description and round brackets for html link.

Like this.

`[use]` `(https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions)`

Note: no space in between the pair of these brackets.

Comment: [Use](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) *Test link*

Answer (score 10):

You can use inline links:

```
[chemistry.se](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com)
```

They contract nicely to [chemistry.se](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com). That works everywhere, also in chat.

In normal posts, you can use this markdown for pictures, too, simply add an exclamation mark in front of it. As images are not allowed in comments, they will be displayed as links instead, with an exclamation pint in front of it. (See example comment below.)

```
![The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu3sW.png)
```

In normal posts, you can combine the two:

```
[![The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu3sW.png)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table)
```

[image: The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!]

Comment: Nice one had never done it with a picture!

Comment: `![The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wu3sW.png)` = ![The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wu3sW.png) || `[![The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wu3sW.png)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table)` = [![The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wu3sW.png)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) {Very weird indeed.}